# Who are the “elders” in Isaiah 24:23?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 24:23 NASB

> “Then the moon will be abashed and the sun ashamed, For the Lord of hosts will reign on Mount Zion and in Jerusalem, And His glory will be before His elders.”
> ‭‭

Who are the “elders” mentioned here?

Answer (score 1):

Ibn Ezra - Commentary on [Isaiah 24:23] regarding זְקֵנָיו Zeqenav:"His-Elders" (those with זְקָנִים Beards) :

> "those that remain faithful to God. According to others this passage refers to the worshippers of the heavenly bodies"

https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.24.23?with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang=bi

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's the same heavenly Elders discussed by John who sit around The Throne:

> Revelation 4:2-4 At once I was in the Spirit, and behold, a throne stood in heaven, with one seated on the throne. And he who sat there had the appearance of jasper and carnelian, and around the throne was a rainbow that had the appearance of an emerald. Around **the throne were twenty-four thrones, and seated on the thrones were twenty-four elders,** clothed in white garments, with golden crowns on their heads.